# Visual Studio Image Resource Dialog Open in design mode UI editor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm creating a UI editor for a control I made.  Basically the user can double click to open a dialog to set properties like color, text, etc.  I would like to add a way to set the images.  In the control's properties it will open the resource dialog.  Is there a way to open this dialog from an event, button click, in design mode?

I'm using VS2017, vb.net.

Comment: do you want a user to let choose an image while run-time? with a dialog box?

Comment: No, this is only design mode.  Currently in design mode when the user clicks on the image property it will open the dialog, I want this same dialog to open in a UI design mode form.

Comment: Just curious if anyone has any thoughts on this...